# Ruby on Rails - Selecting a range from a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a query to get all the purchases from the db. For example

```
orders = PurchaseOrders.all
```

I in the same query, how can I select only the first hundred orders(1-100) or just the next 100(101-200) etc..?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `limit` and `offset`:

```
PurchaseOrders.limit(200).offset(100)
```

which meant start from 200 and take 100 records. [More info here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset). Or with `take`:

```
PurchaseOrders.offset(100).take(400)
```

take 400 records starting from 100.

Answer (score 0):

For the first 100 records;

```
orders = PurchaseOrders.first(100)
```

and last 100 records;

```
orders = PurchaseOrders.last(100)
```

or by IDs,

```
orders = PurchaseOrders.find([100, 201])
```

Comment: What if 100 to 201 have different ids? For example 100 has 4000 for id?

Comment: Your finding records with IDs between 100 and 201. That is what i could think of.